# Datagridview Combobox columns won't dropdown (C#)

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview filled with 8 columns of comboboxes, and 32 rows.

```
    private void frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Make 32 rows total
        for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
        PopulateComboBoxes();
    }
```

and I've also added some items to each of them. For some reason they won't drop down when I click them.

I have looked around, but nothing seems to work.

edit:
It just adds each of the dropdown options in

```
    public void PopulateDropDowns()
    {
        //Get Errors
        DataSet Errors = SendQueryReturnDataSet("SELECT * FROM DB.Errors");
        DataTable dt_Errors = Errors.Tables[0];

        //Populate all Drop Downs
        for (int i = 0; i < dt_Errors.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x<8; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
                {
                    (grid_Wafer.Rows[x].Cells[y] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items.Add(dt_Errors.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `PopulateComboBoxes()` be the relevant code to share?

Comment: Well right now it just puts the items into the list that should dropdown when it's clicked.

Comment: In the first snippet, your grid is `DataGridView1` and in the second snippet, it's `grid_Wafer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateComboBoxes();
    // Make 32 rows total
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
}

private void PopulateComboBoxes()
{
    //for each column, set as combobox, then populate
    var cName = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cName.Items.Add("John Galt");
    cName.Items.Add("Tim Duncan");
    cName.Items.Add("King Leonidas");
    var cAddress = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cAddress.Items.Add("Main Street");
    cAddress.Items.Add("Broad Street");
    cAddress.Items.Add("Market Street");

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cName);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cAddress);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like this. What I found in the debugger was the DataGridViewComboBoxCells had their ReadOnly property set True. This was despite me leaving the property as False for the whole column when I created it in the design mode. I couldn't find anywhere the cells or column were getting set to read only. In my code I switch read only off after assigning to the data source and the combo boxes seem to drop fine now.

Edit: I discovered that the RowTemplate for the grid had Readonly set True, which was causing this problem. I think it  must have happened when I was trying out a variety of settings.

Answer (score 1):

We need more information to solve this one accurately. Can you show us your front end code and maybe your PopulateComboBoxes() method?

Some things that come to mind, off the top of my head...

- For some reason your drop downs are not getting populated properly (do a view source of your page to see if the items are actually being added to your drop down lists)
- Maybe a styling issue? (check your z-index properties and make sure nothing is at a higher stack then your drop-downs. try setting your drop-downs z-index to 99999)

Still even with my above suggestion, I need to see more of the code to give a proper answer.

Comment: I also notice that you may be working in winforms, which is something that may help pointing out in the future. However, if you are dealing with webforms my above bullets are helpful... :)

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this one a few times and found that if the DataGridView ComboBox column is bound to a read-only field (i.e. no setter defined), it will display as read only. If you try the answer suggested by Rob Hincliff, you'll get this exception: *DataGridView column bound to a read-only field must have ReadOnly set to True*

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very old thread but may useful to someone. I had a similar issue and in my case was because I had CellMouseDown event for DGV where I used it to show some right-clicked menu.
In that event I was only interested on right-click and cleared selection when it was a left-click on DGV; which is the one dropping the menu in combobox. So I rewrote the event and all fine.